# Check if a string does NOT contain some text

Tags: vb.net, string, text, contains

```
If String1.Contains("something") AndAlso String2.'does not contain something'
    'do stuff
End If
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I've tried with

```
If String1.Contains("something") AndAlso Not String2.Contains("something else")
    'do stuff
End If
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: what do you mean, it doesn't work? Do you suggest there is a problem with the implementation of `String.Contains` or `Not`? What is the value of `String2`, I suspect that you have a difference in case.

Comment: Are you intentionally omitting `Not` from the first call to `Contains()`?

Comment: Also if newlines are involved, you may be running into an issue with `LF` vs. `CRLF` (or `LFCR`).

Comment: Can you give an example of strings that don't work and the expected result?

Answer (score 10):

okay, we have a string,

```
Dim someString = "this something that"
```

the expression

```
someString.Contains("something")
```

evaluates to `True`. The expression

```
someString.Contains("something else")
```

evaluates to `False`. The expression

```
Not someString.Contains("something else")
```

evaluates to `True`.

---

Note:

The expression

```
someString.Contains("Something")
```

evaluates to `False` becuase `"Something"` fails an Ordinal Case-Sensitive comparison with `"something"`. Unless specified otherwise, string comparisons are Ordinal Case-Sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Just use IndexOf on the two strings and then use the if expression

```
Dim pos1 = String1.IndexOf("something") 
Dim pos2 = String2.IndexOf("something else")

if pos1 < 0 AndAlso pos2 < 0 then
    ' the string1 doesn't contain "something" and string2 doesn't contain "something else"
End If
```

string.IndexOf returns the character position of the string passed as argument. If the argument is not found in the source string the return is -1 as explained in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx)

IndexOf could also be useful if your search term contains characters in different case than the input string.
For example, if your input text contains the word "Something" (Uppercase 'S') searching this input using the term "something" will fail both using Contains or the vanilla IndexOf.
But with IndexOf you could write something like this

```
Dim pos1 = String1.IndexOf("something", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
Dim pos2 = String2.IndexOf("something else", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

This will force IndexOf to treat "Something" and "something" like they are the same string.

Finally, your question is unclear if you want to check for the missing text only the second string or both strings, but knowing that IndexOf returns >= 0 if the searched string exists then it should be pretty simple to modify the if condition to suit your needs.

Comment: how does that help? Like `Contains` but, more complicated.

Comment: [Contains is implemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/428c5c9954dea844.html) using IndexOf and assume the StringComparison.Ordinal, something that you could change if you need to with IndexOf. So I could say, yes perhaps is more complicated (subjective) but surely it is more flexible (objective)

Comment: using `IndexOf` is more complex because you need to test the result for equality with `-1`. However, as you have amended your question to say, `IndexOf` does have overloads that accept a `StringComparison` parameter. I see no subjectivity but, that could be subjective.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim String1 As String = "This one contains something at index 18"
Dim String2 As String = "You won't find your string here !"

Debug.WriteLine("String1 : IndexOf(something) = " _
    + String1.IndexOf("something").ToString())
Debug.WriteLine("String2 : IndexOf(something else) = " _
    + String1.IndexOf("something else").ToString())

If String1.Contains("something") AndAlso Not String2.Contains("something else") Then
    Debug.WriteLine("String1 contains [something]")
    Debug.WriteLine("String2 doesn't contain [something else]")
End If
```

The above code outputs :

```
'String1 : IndexOf(something) = 18
'String2 : IndexOf(something else) = -1
'String1 contains [something]
'String2 doesn't contain [something else]
```

The addition of **`Not`** right in front of `String.Contains(blah)` definately means **`the String doesn't contain [blah]`**. I don't see anything wrong with `Not Contains`..

What's wrong with your code ? Or what's wrong with your variables and their *actual* content ? Or have you lost track of your variables somwhere ? Carefull of upper/lower cases in values AND variables names (even if it's known VB doesn't care, avoid casing megamix)

> Use a **`Breakpoint`** just before your **`If`** condition test, then run the
>   debugger. Have a look at **`String1`** and **`String2`** contents.

Answer (score -1):

You can use vbNullString to check if the string contains a text or not. Try this code:

```
If String1.Text = vbNullString AND String2.Text = vbNullString Then
'do stuff
else
'the string is empty
End if
```